# Is loading too many views bad practice? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some jquery at the bottom of the page, some functions are needed on certain page and I was thinking of separating everything in different views and loading each group of functions when needed.

My question is, is it bad practice to load to many views in a view performance wise or do they work like include() and it doesn't really matter how many I have?

Example would look like this:

```
    <?php echo $this->load->view('media/view/_commonjs'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('media/view/_ratingjs'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('media/view/_watch_listjs'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->load->view('media/view/_videojs'); ?>
```

The idea would be to show jquery functions only when they'll be used.

Comment: I'd argue it's more important what exactly it is that you're loading in the views rather than how many views you're loading.

Comment: I don't think the quantity matters, although if you find yourself repeating these over and over again, consider creating a helper that does this automatically with a template.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't really matter. There aren't any limits.